# ASPNETZERO - Basic index list view error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working on ASPNETZERO .NET Core MVC template. I want to setup a simple index view with tiles instead of datatables or Jtable grid. I am following the example from the docs [here](https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step-Core#creating-the-page). I copied the code for the app service index method. I copied the view model code. I then applied the code to my index view CSHTML. As soon as I write the foreach line of code and put in model. the intellisense does not show anything. I am able to compile the code, but when I run the page, I get the error message shown below.

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'CompanyIndexViewModel' because 'CompanyIndexViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I need some help with this error. Also, if anyone has a code example of how I can display a simple index view with tiles instead of using a grid, please do share. I have the css/html for tiles look working. I am able to create an app service that returns a list object of my entity. I just cant seem to figure out how to get it to work on the index.cshtml page and the related index.js. I have done this many times outside of the ABP templates. I am struggling to make this work within the context of the ABP template.

Here is the view model code.

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(ListResultDto<CompanyListDto>))]
public class CompanyIndexViewModel
{
    public CompanyIndexViewModel(ListResultDto<CompanyListDto> output)
    {
        output.MapTo(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are doing `foreach (var item in Model)`, and Model is of type CompanyIndexViewModel and is not a list of some sort, then this will fail.  You need to do `foreach (var item in Model.Items)`: replace "Items" with whatever the collection-based property inside the view model is.

Comment: @BrianMains - I just updated my post with my view model class code. This is the same as the one in shown in the ABP docs. Also, when I type in model. items is not one of the options. I have only four options like ToString() and three other similar ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit `ListResultDto<CompanyListDto>` as shown [here](https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step-Core#using-getpeople-method-from-mvc-controller):

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(ListResultDto<CompanyListDto>))]
public class CompanyIndexViewModel : ListResultDto<CompanyListDto>
{
    public CompanyIndexViewModel(ListResultDto<CompanyListDto> output)
    {
        output.MapTo(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can access `Model.Items` in `Index.cshtml` as shown [here](https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step-Core#rendering-people-in-mvc-view):

```
@foreach (var company in Model.Items)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my issue for now.

I updated my view model with below code.

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(ListResultDto<CompanyListDto>))]
public class CompanyIndexViewModel
{
    public IReadOnlyList<CompanyListDto> Companies { get; }

    public CompanyIndexViewModel(IReadOnlyList<CompanyListDto> companies)
    {
        Companies = companies;
    }
}
```

I then updated my controller code to below.

```
 var output = _companyAppService.GetCompanyList(input);
 var model = new CompanyIndexViewModel(output.Items);
 return View(model);
```

I got this solution from reading this article [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115763/Using-ASP-NET-Core-Entity-Framework-Core-and-ASP-N)